# dynamic href call tag ionic 3 app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, href, android-dialer

I am trying to add a href call action to my Ionic 3 app. I have the phone number stored in a binding `{{item.phone}}`

I need to add this to an href tag in order to open the phones native app. I am not sure how to bind it to the href tag

```
<ion-col col-10 href="......">{{item.phone}}</ion-col>
```

Please assist

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to do.

But you can bind to dynamic `href` like this

```
<ion-col col-10 [href]="item.phone">{{item.phone}}</ion-col>
```

or

```
<ion-col col-10 href={{item.phone}}>{{item.phone}}</ion-col>
```

Comment: What I want to achieve is when the user clicks on the item ie. phone number, the user will get redirected to the phones native dialler. eg href="tel:+27800236368"

Comment: ok so this worked `<ion-col col-10><a ion-item no-padding href="tel:{{item.phone}}" target="_top">{{item.phone}}</a></ion-col>`
, needed to add an a-tag and add tel: